# Indian National with valid US visa on old passport wants to enter Philippines

Tags: visas, philippines

I am Indian national/ passport holder. I am traveling to Philippines for business. In Philippines, visa on arrival is granted to persons traveling with valid USA visa. I have valid USA visa **in my old passport**.

Will they object? Will I be able to get visa on arrival with carrying both old passport with Valid USA visa and new passport?

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't have any objections: visa is issued for a person, not a passport.

It is a very common situation to have valid visas in expired passport and present both of them at the migration control

Comment: As you are traveling for business, you should do a quick analysis: cost of Philippine visa versus potential cost of lost opportunity if they turn you away